# Save websocket price stream to local DB

Tags: python, mysql, websocket, stream

I am developing a script to save a stream of prices received via websocket to a local database but I am facing some design dilemma.

The stream consists of 1 minute candlestick data of around 200 instruments received via a cryptocurrency exchange websocket. When closed new candles are received I want to save them to a local db.

I started building it in Python with a MySQL DB but I am dubious on feasibility.
Apologies for not posting code, this is more a design/architecture dilemma

Questions:

1. Can I save the messages directly to DB or would I need an
   intermediate step? (Performance concern)
2. Is Python the best option or should I look at Javascript or some 3rd
   party software?
3. Am I totally out of my mind for building this? I have a strategy
   that needs historical data from many instruments and calling Rest
   API is not possible as I would hit the rate limit therefore looking
   a working with Websockets

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are/were you forcing it to batch the transactions?  I achieved something quite like this using just bash, but needed the "intermediate step" you'd mentioned of first writing to a FIFO, and then doing a buffered read (via LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE) from the FIFO, and finally forcing batching by injecting commits per every 500-1000 or so lines.

Answer (score 1):

1 - I don't know if it's the best idea to save 200 values per minute, you can store the average, the highest and the lowest values ?

If you want to store all values you can use influxdb :

> ```
> InfluxDB Cloud is the most powerful time series database as a service — free to start, easy to use, fast, serverless, elastic scalability.
> ```

2 - I think python is appropriate for this use

3 - If you can't use API rest, websocket can be a good idea.
When I had the opportunity to work on massive temporal data (IOT sensors), I used influxdb for storage, and MQTT for communication

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can. As an JSON string or direct into the table, but that depends on the form of the data. If its format don't change I would save it directly into the table. When the format can change (often) I would do both and save the raw data as a kind of fail save.
2. Python should work. Inserting Data into a database should be no problem with most languages. Use the one you have the most experience/ feel most comfortable with or want to lern.
3. This kind of Programm is an good exercise for learning a new language or programming in general. And I don't think that 200 Datasets per minute is to much to handle. So I don't think your out of your mind, actually most programmers I know have build something like this at some point.